# How to convert JSON input to map<string,string> format of Athena in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, parquet, amazon-athena, pyarrow

My Athena column datatype is `map<string,string>`. I am trying to show a JSON format on Athena.

My input in a parquet file -

```
{"Datawarehouse":"Package/PackageBody/Portfolio/MuniSectorBreakdown", "DividendBreakdown":"Package/Dividend"}
```

Output on Athena -

```
{"Package/PackageBody/Portfolio/MuniSectorBreakdown"="Package/Dividend"}
```

It is showing the correct output in a parquet file but not on Athena. How can I get the same output on Athena? How should we generate a parquet file which supports `map<string,string>` in Athena using Python?

Comment: pls show some code

Comment: This is not a valid json

Comment: I have CSV File having one column input as json. I'm converting it in parquet so that I can show it it on athena. In parquet file it is showing dict datatype for that json input column. In Athena I have taken map<string,string> datatype. I have shown above parquet file input and Athena output. Currently I'm reading doing json.loads() to convert string to json but after generating parquet it is showing different output as mentioned above

Comment: Instead of showing {key1:value1, key2:value2} it is showing {value1=value2} on athena

Comment: df = '''{"Datawarehouse"="Package/PackageBody/Portfolio/MuniSectorBreakdown", "DividendBreakdown"="Package/Dividend"}'''

df1 = json.loads(df.replace('=',':'))

code snippet before converting to parquet